# Однородные, объединенные причинной связью

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли данные определения рассматривать как определения, связанные причинно-следственной связью: В один из зимних, морозных дней... (зимняя, а потому морозная)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Вариант 1 (классический):** В один из **морозных зимних** дней. Неоднородные прилагательные, обозначают разные признаки, ближе к предмету находится определение с более постоянным признаком. "Стоял **морозный зимний** день" (16 примеров в Нацкорпусе).

**Сближение признаков как авторское исключение:** **Морозный, зимний вечер,** блеск фонарей, неистовые «пади» бойкого кучера, мелькание экипажей и ярко освещенных магазинов ― все это представляло какую-то дикую, не лишенную непонятной прелести картину. [А. К. Шеллер-Михайлов. Господа Обносковы (1868)]

**2) Вариант 2 (более свободный):** В один из **зимних морозных** дней. Строгий порядок определений нарушен, что может расцениваться как некоторое сближение признаков; поэтому возможна постановка запятой, но обычно она всё-таки не ставится. "Зимний морозный день близился к концу" (6 примеров).

**3) Вариант 3. Три определения (два однородных и одно неоднородное):** "Стоял ясный, морозный зимний день".

Answer (score 1):

Ваше "зимняя, а потому морозная" весьма сомнительно, т. к. зима может быть и не морозной, также, к примеру, морозные дни случаются и осенью. Так что это не то, чем кажется вам.